# Rotating point by angle

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

Let $X = (c, 0)$. If I will rotate $X$ by, say, angle $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}$, how can I determine position of new angle?

Will it just be $X' = (c + \cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be $(c\cos(\alpha),c\sin(\alpha))$

The distance of the point from the origin $(0,0)$ is $c$.

Initially, the angle was $0^o$ and now it is $\alpha^o$

So, the point becomes $(c\cos(\alpha),c\sin(\alpha))$

Comment: And $c\cos(\alpha)$ because $\cos$ is defined on unite cirlce, huh?

Comment: That is a possible explanation, but I thought it in a different way- I edited my answer